# Linker error when using C++ code in iPad app

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm working on an iPad app which uses some C++ code for computation. I already did things like change .m to .mm and add libraries and source files in Build Phases. However, Xcode is still complaining about functions not found.
  The structure of my C++ code is like this:

wrapper.h: (The wrapper function was the main function for C++ code.

```
int wrapper(char* filename);
...
unsigned char* readBMP(char* filename);
...
```

wrapper.mm:

```
int wrapper (char* filename) {
  ...
  unsigned char *imgX;
  imgX = readBMP(filename);
  ...
}
...
unsigned char* readBMP(const char* filename) {
...
}
```

And the error message is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "readBMP(char*)", referenced from:
      wrapper(char*) in wrapper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Could someone help me to solve this?

Comment: Did you add the .mm to the compile sources phase of the project? http://paulsolt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Build-Phases-for-unit-test-in-Xcode-4.png

Comment: Yes. I checked. All m and mm files are in the compile sources under Build Phases tab. I also add libstdc++.dylib to the libraries under the same tab.

Comment: The iPad doesn't use an x86 based device.  It uses an ARM based device.  Are you sure you've set your build targets correctly?

Comment: The "Targeted Device family" row under Build Settings shows iPad. What else should I check for build targets?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by adding necessary const keyword for wrapper function's parameter. Somehow it's not a warning in Xcode. Instead it causes a link error. I guess Xcode is strict on this.

Comment: It's not Xcode; it's C++. `readBMP(char*)` and `readBMP(const char*)` are two different functions. `wrapper.h` says that there is a function `readBMP(char*)`; the problem is that that function isn't defined anywhere. The fact that there is a definition of a **different** function `readBMP(const char*)` doesn't change that.